# Simple proof of equation for current through a pn junction directly polarized

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics

I've attending an introductory course in semiconductor physics and I am having some difficulties in find a simple derivation of the equation:
\begin{equation}
I=I_s \left( e^{\frac{V_D}{V_t}} -1 \right) 
\end{equation}

<del>During the lecture the professor started with the following equation without tell about its source:</del>

$$
\Phi = \frac{\ln(x-l)}{2\tau} + \frac{\ln(x+l)}{2\tau} = \frac{l}{2\tau}\left[ n(x) - \frac{dn}{dx} l -n(x) - \frac{dn}{dx}l \right] = \frac{l^2}{\tau} \frac{dn}{dx}
$$

<del>Where I imagine $l$ is the diffusion length and $n$ the density of electrons.

Which is the origin of this equation and how can I derive the diode equation from this one?</del>

$$
$$
*The equation above was wrong as I mispelled $l\cdot n(x)$ for $\ln(x-l)$*

Comment: Your first equation is already a simplification of a much more complicated equation, so the 'simple derivation' is, well, not so simple. For now, just go with it unless you want to dive into the Shockley-Read-Hall equations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for $\Phi$ seems to be related to a common a heuristic derivation of the one-dimensional flux density of electrons ( number of electrons per unit time and unit area) due to diffusion. Thus $l$ is **not** the diffusion length, it should be the mean free path between electron collisions, and $\tau$ should be the mean time between collisions. This heuristic derivation, which can be found in many introductory semiconductor device books, usually assumes that the mean velocity of the electrons is the mean thermal velocity $v_{th}=l/\tau$. The factor $\frac{l^2}{\tau}=D_n$ is just the electron diffusion constant. There seems to be a problem with the part of the equation containing logarithmic functions. This part is dimensionally not consistent with the right hand side which is a flux density.